# Rails more than one skip_before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to do more than one skip_before_action

tried this below option:

```
  skip_before_action :user_logged_in, :user_is_provider, only: [:impressum, :agb, :help, :privacy]
```

but the

:user_is_provider

function isn't called yet. The function is in application_controller.rb

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need `skip_before_action` and not `before_action`? You want the method to be executed or skipped?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you `skip_before_action` they will not be executed so it's ok that the function is not called.

Comment: the method should be executed while loading the page. with :user_logged_in it workes perfectly. bevore I call A page the :user_logged_in is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
skip_before_action :user_logged_in
skip_before_action :user_is_provider, only: [:impressum, :agb, :help, :privacy]
```

Comment: thanks, but nothing has changed. In the :user_is_provider is at the moment only a puts "test" but its not printed